# Mixing dynamic and conditional class name in Vue 2

Tags: vuejs2

Let's say I want a div with class `a0` to `a9` according to index in v-for and class `b` conditionally.

To do it separately, it looks like this:

```
<div v-for="(val, index) in array" :class="'a' + index"></div>
```

and

```
<div v-for="(val, index) in array" :class="{'b': index===1}"></div>
```

When we mix them together, given that this does not work:

```
<div v-for="(val, index) in array" :class="{'a' + index: true, 'b': index===1}"></div>
```

and the best (working solution) I can get is this:

```
<div v-for="(val, index) in array" :class="'a' + index + ' ' + (index===1?'b':'') }"></div>
```

Are there any better ways? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div v-for="(val, index) in array" :class="['a'+index, {b: index === 1}]"></div>
```

Or

```
<div v-for="(val, index) in array" :class="['a'+index, index === 1 ? 'b' : '']"></div>
```

Check demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2fxj8hye/).

Comment: The first one should be the best way for now. Thanks!